# WPF: In Expression Blend, how to change Foreground of a custom button with a Border on different states?

Tags: wpf, templates, styles, expression-blend

In Expression Blend 4, I want to change the `Foreground` of a custom button on different states. I'm just able to change the `Background` and `BorderBrush`.

Just like this:

[image]

If the state is "Normal", the color of text "Button" is `Black`, while the state is "Pressed", the color of text "Button" is `White`.

On `Brushes Panel` under `Properties Panel`, there're 3 properties but no `Foreground` property:
[image]

Who can help me? I'm so perplexed.

**Edit**

I find `ContentControl` have a `Foreground` property, but `ContentPresenter` haven't. Wether I should use `ContentControl` instead of `ContentPresenter`?

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have not find some way to change Foreground by Blend(I mean that not in code). In code, just like that:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>

    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ...
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    ...
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    ...
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <ContentPresenter .../>
            ...
</ResourceDictionary>
```